# logstash Mapping Parsing error status 400

Tags: logstash

When I am trying to use logstash to read through a configuration file, I come up with map parsing error.

> :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"logstash-2016.06.07",
>   "_type"=>"txt", "_id"=>nil, "status"=>400,
>   "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "r eason"=>"Failed to
>   parse mapping [*default*]: Mapping definition for [data] has
>   unsupported parameters:  [ignore_above :  1024]",
>   "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"Mapping
>   definition for [data] has unsupported para meters:  [ignore_above :
>   1024]"}}}}, :level=>:warn}←[0m

I found that there is no problem is groking my logs but just do not know what is the matter of the error.

Here is my logstash.conf

```
input{
    stdin{}
    file{
        type => "txt"
        path => "C:\HA\accesslog\trial.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter{
    grok{
    match => {"message" => ["%{IP:ClientAddr}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:access_date}%{SPACE}%{TIME:access_time}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.VirtualHost}%{SPACE}%{WORD:cs-method}%{SPACE}%{PATH:cs-uri-stem}%{SPACE}%{PROG:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.Protocol}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:sc-status}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:bytes}%{SPACE}%{NOTSPACE:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.RequestedSessionId}%{SPACE}%{PROG:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.Ecid}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.ThreadId}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:x-eap.wlsCustomLogField.EndTs}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:time-taken}"]}
        }
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
        drop { }
    }   
}
output{
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        template_overwrite => true
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }   
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please format your error message to be more readable. You may also want to trim the hostnames and potentially sensitive data out of there.

Comment: The error is a 400, failed to index. Please show your output section of your logstash config.

Comment: I have just tried to made the things more clear. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, Did you recently upgrade Logstash or Elasticsearch?

Comment: No, I use the version I downloaded only.

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16283

Comment: So should  I write my own template?

Comment: Yea, thanks. I have get several files similar to this and the method works great for them, but not for this one. Sounds wierd...I have updated my latest output conf file.

Comment: I have solved the problem now, another reason for the problem is that my new created field name are too long for indexing. I have shortened the name and solve the problem collaborating with your solution. Great thanks. It's rock.

Comment: gratz, you should post that as an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114175/discussion-between-kennedy-kan-and-will-barnwell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I turn out find out the sollution here: github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16283
2. Another problem is the created field for indexing is too long. Shortening the name can solve the issue.